# React Native Intl.NumberFormat different display currency between iOS & Android

Tags: react-native, internationalization, expo, intl

I have a React Native Expo app where I'm making use of Intl.NumberFormat(). There is some difference when displaying a number with its currency between iOS & Android.

If the currency is a symbol (€, $...), it displays it in the same way in both platforms.

Example **without symbol**:

```
  let localizedNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat(en-US, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "CHF",
    currencyDisplay: "symbol"
  }).format(10.00);
```

- Output on iOS: "`CHF 10.00`"
- Output on Android: "`CHF10.00`"

Example **with symbol**:

```
  let localizedNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat(en-US, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "EUR",
    currencyDisplay: "symbol"
  }).format(10.00);
```

- Output on iOS: "`€10.00`"
- Output on Android: "`€10.00`"

The difference in the end is that, when the currency is not a symbol, it adds a white space on iOS but not on Android.

I've been doing tests on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat and iOS seems the same than web version.

(Note I've tested it with CHF, but it also happens with PLN, etc & I've also tested in a native app and Android behaves differently)

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Oh interesting, I would like to know how it is working the Intl object in your expo project ? I'm using the expo sdk 41, which version is yours ? Thank you

Comment: Besides this little issue, we have no problem. Right now, we're using sdk 44

Comment: Nice, as I can't update the sdk by now, I fixed installing the polyfill manually like said in here https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/, and now it is working like a charm ;)